# UIWebView background color with UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight is always white

Tags: ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview, pagination

I have a problem with UIWebView pagination

you can easily repeat it:
add uiwebview as a subview. then

```
_webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_webView.opaque = NO;
[_webView loadHTMLString:@"some string" baseURL:nil];
```

Now you have transparent background of UIWebView. But if you set

```
_webView.paginationMode = UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight;
```

it appears with white background. Am I missing something? Why pagination mode changes background color?

Comment: possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031092/uiwebview-paginationmode-always-show-white-background-how-to-make-it-transparen?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If your webview can't fill full page, rest of the website will be white color block view. It is system default action.
You can custom it by adding your view to that space to make the background look the same as your webview content.

```
// omit create webView and colorView
let script = "document.documentElement.offsetHeight"
let contentHeight = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(script)
let frameHeight = webView.frame.height
let lastPageHeight = frameHeight * CGFloat(webView.pageCount) - CGFloat(Double(contentHeight!)!)

colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

colorView.frame = CGRectMake(webView.frame.width * CGFloat(webView.pageCount-1), webView.frame.height - lastPageHeight, webView.frame.width, lastPageHeight)
```

refer to https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27906